# Make transparent this black procedural emission using Combine XYZ and Value nodes?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes, procedural, emission

I'm trying to use these CombineXYZ and Value nodes for transparency and emission.

Edit: I'm trying to make the "Sphere" emission transparent, especially the black part.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please be more specific about you want to achieve, in the text of your post? Am I right, thinking, negative light, not visible to the camera?

Comment: Thanks, I just edited that

Comment: Not sure but is this what you want to achieve ? [![sphere center is transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjPlb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjPlb.png) If so, do you absolutely need those XYZ value nodes ? I did not use them.

Comment: Um, no. I needed black within that red sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, set your Transparent to white, your Emission to red, and invert their sockets in the Mix Shader node.

---

I think we need to address a couple thing more than just addressing your question, because there are a lot of things you do in your shader tree that don't make any sense and would actually harm you in more complex shaders.

### Node inputs

These three Value nodes are useless:

[image]

You can set the node's values in the node. No need to use computing time with extra nodes that do the exact same thing as not having them.

Similarly, no need of an extra node to set a color:

[image]

The only time you ever need a Combine node is when you want to shuffle channels or combine channels from different float data.

For both the Transparent BSDF and Emission nodes, you use 4 extra nodes to set their respective colors. It's only 8 nodes in total for your shader tree, but if you did this in a shader tree with hundreds of colors, that would be 800 extra nodes to compute for "nothing".

We could already simplify your shader tree to this:

[image]

### Transparent Shader

If you want pure transparency, your Transparent BSDF should be pure white. The darker the color, the less transparency you get, black will give you zero transparency. Going over white (using values over 1) will cause your transparency to glow. Using colors will make the transparency only partial and tinted.

But again, if here you want full transparency, use pure white:

[image]

### Emission Shader

You can emit every color, except black. Black is the absence of light. The darker the color, the less emission it can have. See the Strenght as a multiplier of the color. If you set the color to black (0;0;0), you end up with a multiplication by zero no matter the strenght. The opposite is also true: you can't emit any color with zero strenght.

If you want to absorb light, you would need to use a white color with a negative strength.

If you want to emit a color, just set that color:

[image]

### Redundancy

That's more nit-picking here ; strictly speaking, your Power and Color Ramp don't do the same thing, but the end result could be achieved by the Color Ramp node alone:

[image]

The power node essentially darkens your data, which you can do by moving the color stops in the color ramp.

[image]

### Mix nodes order

Anytime you meet a node mixing two data with a factor, understand that the factor is a value from 0 to 1, and the the two data are respectively 0 and 1 from top to bottom.

If the factor is 0, the first data is displayed. If the factor is 1, the second data is displayed.

In your case, the factor is that fresnel you inverted in your color ramp. It is white in the center and black in the outline of the sphere.

So if you want to have the Transparent shader in the center, you must plug it in the socket that is displayed by the factor of 1. Which is the bottom socket.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I'll look into it for sure